# Exported shell scripts for parent & child projects

Tags: bazel

I am in the scenario where I have a "Parent" Bazel project containing some shell scripts & macros. This project must be reused by a "Child" project. The minimal "working" example to reproduce the problem is defined as follow:

**Directory structure**

```
├── Child
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── WORKSPACE
└── Parent
    ├── a_command.bzl
    ├── a_script.sh
    ├── BUILD
    └── WORKSPACE
```

**Parent project files**

*Parent/a_script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
date
```

*Parent/a_command.bzl*

```
def a_command(name):
    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = [],
        outs = [name+".txt"],
        cmd = "$(location :a_script_sh) > $@",
        tools = [":a_script_sh"],
    )
```

*Parent/BUILD*

```
sh_binary(
    name = "a_script_sh",
    srcs = ["a_script.sh"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

*Parent/WORKSPACE*

```
# empty file
```

**Child project files**

*Child/WORKSPACE*

```
local_repository(
    name = "Parent",
    path = "../Parent/",    
)
```

*Child/BUILD*

```
load("@Parent//:a_command.bzl","a_command")

# Uncomment me for a working solution
# alias(name="a_script_sh",actual="@Parent//:a_script_sh")

a_command("use_script")
```

**Now my question**

If I type in the *Child project directory*

```
bazel build //...
```

I get

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: missing input file '//:a_script_sh'.
ERROR: PATH/Child/BUILD:5:1: //:use_script: missing input file '//:a_script_sh'.
Target //:use_script failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: PATH/Child/BUILD:5:1 1 input file(s) do not exist.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.162s, Critical Path: 0.00s
```

Now if I uncomment the line

```
alias(name="a_script_sh",actual="@Parent//:a_script_sh")
```

in the *Child/BUILD* file, everything is working properly:

```
INFO: Found 2 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.191s, Critical Path: 0.03s
```

And the file *use_script.txt* is properly generated into the *Child/bazel-genfiles* directory.

**My question is**:

Does the use of the

```
alias(name="a_script_sh",actual="@Parent//:a_script_sh")
```

is the **right** way to do thing?

I was expecting that it was **Bazel job to resolve this dependency**.

I was not expecting **to have to explicitly redefine** where the *a_script.sh* file is. I think this is awkward, redundant and error prone.

I suspect that I am not doing things the right way and I would be very thankful to anyone who could clearly explaining us how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thank you for the clear and thorough repro instructions!

You found a very interesting scenario! Yet everything is working as intended.

`a_command` in `Parent/a_command.bzl` wraps a genrule with `tools=[":a_script_sh"]`. This is a relative label, relative to the current package, where "current" is the package where the macro is used, not where it is declared. Therefore the Child's BUILD file must declare an "a_script_sh" target (any target with this name) and the example will work.

This behavior makes even more sense in case of `glob`: if a Skylark macro wraps a rule with `srcs=glob([**])`, the macro should pick up files from the current package (where the macro is used), not the foreign one (where the macro is declared).

On top of adding a filegroup to child/BUILD, I also modified the genrule slightly to print the path of "a_script_sh" instead of executing it:

`parent/a_command.bzl`:

```
def a_command(name):
  native.genrule(
      name = name,
      srcs = [],
      outs = [name+".txt"],
      cmd = "echo $(location :a_script_sh) > $@",  # modified
      tools = [":a_script_sh"],
  )
```

`child/BUILD`:

```
load("@Parent//:a_command.bzl","a_command")

# Uncomment me for a working solution
# alias(name="a_script_sh",actual="@Parent//:a_script_sh")

a_command("use_script")
filegroup(name = 'a_script_sh', srcs = ['BUILD'])  # added
```

I couldn't find any way to ensure that the macro would always use the Parent package's `//:a_script_sh` target. The macro shouldn't prefix the label with a repository name (e.g. `"@Parent//:a_script_sh"`) because there's no guarantee that this repo will be bound as "Parent".

The only way I found to work around this problem is to inject the `tools` dependency like so:

`parent/a_command.bzl`:

```
def a_command(name, tools):
  native.genrule(
      name = name,
      srcs = [],
      outs = [name+".txt"],
      cmd = "echo $(location %s) > $@" % tools['a_script_sh'],
      tools = [tools['a_script_sh']],
  )
```

`child/BUILD`:

```
load("@Parent//:a_command.bzl","a_command")

a_command(
    "use_script",
    tools = {"a_script_sh": "@Parent//:a_script_sh"},
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your positive feedback and explanations. As you wrote yourself: the macro is extended where it is used (it s only a macro after all :-) ), and we can not prefix //:a_script_sh because we do not know future bounding in Child projects. Like I am learning Bazel I feared that I missed something... Again thanks